# Laravel - Register Custom Notification Channel from array

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a custom notification channel in Laravel, by following the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#custom-channels).

The custom channel class is called `TeamsBotChannel`, and I can easily use it by doing the below:

```php
public function via($notifiable){
  
    return [TeamsBotChannel::class];

}
```

Now, in my database, I store my users notification preferences in a table. In the `via` method, I want to query these and return them, so users can decide what channels they want to be notified on.

This can look like the below:

```php
public function via($notifiable){
    
    $channels = $notifiable->channels->toArray();
    //$channels return an array: ['email', 'slack', 'msteams']
     
}
```

Now my problem is, how can I link the `msteams` value to my custom channel `TeamsBotChannel`? I can easily just return `email` and `slack` in the `via` method, but for a custom channel, I need to reference the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was simply just:

```php
public function via($notifiable){
    
    $channels = $notifiable->channels;
    return $channels->map(function($item){
    
      return $item == 'msteams' ? TeamsBotChannel::class : $item;

    })->toArray();
     
}
```